# Meteor SimpleSchema Repeated Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I'm wondering if there's a simple way of doing this. First this is my current schema:

```
Test.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  owner: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Owner of the test',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name of the test',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Date of test creation',
  },

  // MY QUESTION IS FOR THE OBJECT BELOW

  [LOVE]: {
    type: Object,
    label: `Configuration for ${LOVE}`,
  },
  [LOVE.one]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.two]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.three]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.four]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.five]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.six]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.seven]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.eight]: { type: Boolean },
  [LOVE.nine]: { type: Boolean },
});
```

Where I have the LOVE variable, I would like it to be equal to multiple values so that I don't have to write the same schema over and over.

I thought I could use something like regex but I don't know. Can someone help?

Comment: What regex would you like to use to recognize (one, two, three ... a.s.o) ?
Maybe i got something wrong, but why not use a collection for Love Objects instead ? 
Or maybe there is a preprocessor that can insert according to a template, so you dont have to write it over and over ... if so ...

Comment: The variable LOVE should be equal to many values so I can just write that part once. The keys one, two, three and so on is always same for every different values of LOVE. My bad, I hope that was more clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a nested schema:

```
lovers = new SimpleSchema({
  one:   {type: boolean},
  two:   {type: boolean},
  three: {type: boolean},
  four:  {type: boolean},
  five:  {type: boolean},
  six:   {type: boolean},
  seven: {type: boolean},
  eight: {type: boolean},
  nine:  {type: boolean},
});
```

and then reuse it in your original schema:

```
Test.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  owner: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Owner of the test',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name of the test',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Date of test creation',
  },
  LOVE:    { type: lovers },
  PASSION: { type: lovers },
  DESIRE:  { type: lovers },
  etc...
});
```

Hopefully this is what you were after.

Comment: Thank you for this example, I'm glad I came here.  [Here is a link to the documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) for those coming in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It should imho be

```
  relations : { type : [boolean] }
```

So then you would have

```
 LOVE.relations
```

as a collection of say 8 entries. No need to constraint it to these 8 i assume.

You might use a different term, maybe *affairs* or a better match, but the idea behind is just to use it the way a collection is meant to be used for the purpose.